# Oracle apex_json.parse, SPEED

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-apex

I have JSON about 6 600 000 rows.
And I parse it with apex_json and insert it into tables in the database. JSON contains about 120 categories.

This process takes about an hour to finish.
Is there a way how to speed up the parse? Or things that I should avoid? 
Type I use the most is get_varchar2(below the text)
The biggest level I dig is p2.

Thank you for any suggestions.

```
APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2 (
p_path             IN VARCHAR2,
p0                 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p1                 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p2                 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p3                 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p4                 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_default          IN BOOLEAN  DEFAULT) NULL,
p_values           IN t_values DEFAULT g_values )
```

Comment: I make that about 1,800 rows being processed per second - pretty impressive performance really!  I think you'd need a very different approach from extracting values one at a time using `apex_json.get_varchar2` to make it any faster, but I'm not at all sure what that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, that the translating encoded characters is the main speed problem. It is all done in 8min without translating. And that fit my needs. Ty for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have almost the same case, except that the data come to rest web service in json format.
We find out that the most slow part is `apex_json.parse()` procedure, 
I suppose migrating to oracle 12.2 with SQL/JSON  instead of the apex_json package  will help.